# how to get data with last condition = register?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, where-clause

well FYI this is my first post, so i don't really know about the rule here,

i just stuck in selecting data from my db, here's some of my data.

```
Table (Monster_card)
mons_card_id | Level
    1           1
    2           1
    3           1
    4           1
Table (Monster_registration)
mons_reg_id |mons_card_id | status      | time(timestamp)
    1            1         "REGISTER"    "2012-07-09 12:00:00"
    2            1         "UNREGISTER"  "2012-11-01 12:49:01"
    3            2         "REGISTER"    "2012-11-03 12:49:01"
    4            3         "REGISTER"    "2012-11-04 12:49:01"
```

my current query is =

```
select a.mons_card_id from monster_card a, monster_registration b
where b.status = "REGISTER"
```

;

my desired result = by the data above, the result should only mons_card_id 2 & 3.
                    but in my current result, mons_card 1 also shown up.

sorry for the incomplete post before.

any suggestion?

Comment: How do you define "last"?

Comment: Show your desired result.

Comment: the records where inserted randomly on the table, so by that, it is hard to tell which one is the last one. if you have extra row that controls their last status by date. it would be great.

Comment: "last" means that the mons_id currently register, because i tried to select the data but the result is showing all the mons_id

Comment: @danield How do you define "currently" in terms of the data?

Comment: @danield this is just a suggestion, add new column for date of their status. eg `mons_ID, status, DATE`

Comment: Last Status based on what?? .. a datetime column should exist.

Comment: yes, i have datetime coloumn, i will edit my post then

Comment: is the table defined with (or without) OIDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to make sure there are no more recent records with a status other than "REGISTER" for a given mons_card_id

```
SELECT mons_card_id
FROM monster_registration M
WHERE M.status = 'REGISTER' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM monster_registration R
    WHERE R.mons_card_id = M.mons_card_id
        AND R.time > M.time 
        AND R.status <> 'REGISTER'
)
```

Working [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/efa4b/2)

Comment: You're welcome!  Since it's your first post, I can shamelessly remind you to accept an answer if you find it is correct :)